# Is [websites] a meta tag, or just a tag with two legitimate meanings?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

After reviewing (and leaving undecided, for now) a [suggested edit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/993) that revealed that the [websites](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites) tag can have both concrete meaning (about developing websites or [having a website](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12279/is-having-your-own-website-important)) and meta-meaning ([websites about X](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/756/programming-puzzles)), I am not sure what to do with it.

- This [seems like a meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) but, is it?  After all, if it is, then isn't [books](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) also?
- If it is a meta tag in one form, then how do we stop its growth, even if we untag all the meta-usages?

Comment: Yea, I saw those proposed edits too and left them undecided as well for this same reason.

Answer (score 4):

Looking through a few questions, I think it'd be reasonable to keep [websites](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites) as a tag denoting web-based resources. Training materials are potentially within the scope of our site, so that seems reasonable.

Many questions asking for resources fall into the "not constructive" bucket, but periodically there are ones worth preserving, so I hesitate to argue for the complete removal of the tag and the questions that go with it.

For the concrete meaning, we have the [web-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development) tag, which I think should be used instead of [websites](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites) when the question deals with developing websites.